# What is the difference between "end up in" and "end in"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *end up in* and *end in*? For example:

> My attempt to cook chicken **ended up in** a complete mess.
>
> My attempt to cook chicken **ended in** a complete mess.

Comment: In your examples, there is no difference. (It's _attempt_, by the way.) But if I were to say "The bus didn't come so I ended up having to walk", I can't omit the _up_.

Comment: @KateBunting That's a great example - one that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in these examples either is correct.

> **My attempt to cook chicken ended up in a complete mess.** - *My attempt at cooking has brought me to the situation where I was in a complete mess.*
>
> **My attempt to cook chicken ended in a complete mess.** - *The result of my attempt at cooking was a complete mess.*

However, in other contexts and scenarios the difference may very from just a shade of meaning to a broad change of meaning.